# How to do Image Shading using GraphicsMagick?

Tags: javascript, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I need to perform shading operation on an Image. I am trying to use GraphicsMagick library for the same but getting the Command failed error as following:

Arguments(4) [Error: Command failed: gm convert: Unrecognized op…, "", "gm convert: Unrecognized option (-shadow)

I have posted the same on [GraphicsMagick Github](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/769) but did not receive any answers.

Sample code:

```
var fs = require('fs'), gm = require('gm');
gm('camaraman.png')
    .shadow(19, 10)
    .write('shadow1.jpg', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.dir(arguments)
        console.log(this.outname + ' created :: ' + arguments[3])
    }
)
```

**ImageMagic or GraphicsMagic sample example**

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-shadow

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-shade

**Please download the image from below link**

InputImage:

https://lnt-storage.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/USER_2/TileScan_001.tif?X-Amz-Expires=262787&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIZGBI4566U6V4M4A/20190108/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190108T052212Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=493fb53f84457d453977d501828d9b815a53f717b5e54b6442336d04ca58817b

Expected Outputimage :

https://lnt-storage.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/USER_2/TileScan_001_shadingCorr.tif?X-Amz-Expires=262762&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIZGBI4566U6V4M4A/20190108/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190108T052138Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=0e1d770734a565c1c1ab64021d1a39d56b19c51516035c2decd81750c5a4e0c6

Want to perform shading or shadow on the image.

Comment: There is no `.shadow()` method, do you mean `.shade()`?

Comment: It would be best if you post a link to an example of your input and desired output, so that we understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: edited the question with input image and expected image with GM sample example

Comment: That operator looks nontrivial to me. How did you get the expected output image you posted above?

Comment: Expected output image generated using c++ library.Need to generate same output using node js or c#.